# Nested Scroll View Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I have a horizontal recycler view inside vertical nested scroll view.
Everything works fine until there is no item inside recycler view once item added inside recycler view the scroll view starts lagging(not scrolling smoothly)

I have tried almost everything.
  like:
     //recycler view
  `additionalList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Recycler View layout(inside child fragment):

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/add_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@color/grey1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_image" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:id="@+id/additional_art_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_image" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Nested Scroll View Layout(Fragment Container):

```
    <NestedScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:autolabel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/observableScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_below="@id/container_purchase_detail"
            android:id="@+id/container_premium_features"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </FrameLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Put `nested scroll view` inside `frame layout`.

Comment: @jaydroider no luck :(

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava Had you overcame this issue?

Comment: @SrikarReddy unfortunately no

Comment: did anyone overcame this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView than prelolipop devices use this code when you are setting adapter

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    }
```

and set **android:nestedScrollingEnabled false** in layout file in *RecyclerView*

```
  android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```